# cant get values from form

Tags: php, codeigniter

In consequence from yesterdays post as i was trying to transfer some variables between the controller and the view today I am trying to get data from a form and update the db but am having trouble getting those values.

this is function from the controller which is called from the form of the view

```
  function updateRecords(){

    $data2=array('name'=>$this->input->post('first_name'),
    'surname'=>$this->input->post('last_name'),
    'contact'=>$this->input->post('contact'),
    'email'=>$this->input->post('email_address'));
            print_r($data2);
     }
```

when I try to print the data2 array I get: Array ( [name] => [surname] => [contact] => [email] => )

this is the code from the view:

```
  <fieldset style="text-align:left">
  <legend><h2>Edit Clients Details</h2></legend>
  <?php
  $this->load->helper('form');
  echo form_open('site/updateRecords');
  echo form_input('first_name', $records['0']->name);
  echo form_input('last_name', $records['0']->surname);
  echo form_input('contact', $records['0']->contact);
  echo form_input('email_address', $records['0']->email);
  echo validation_errors('<p class="error">');
  echo anchor('site/updateRecords','Save');
  echo form_close();
  ?>
  </fieldset>

  <p>
  <?php echo anchor('site/add','Add clients');?>&nbsp;
  <?php echo anchor('site/members_area','Go Home')?>&nbsp;
  <?php echo anchor('login/logout', 'Logout'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to have the id be accessible. One is to structure the edit page call so that it has the id in it. Normally I do this by setting up my urls to be something like: http://site.com/client/client_id/edit for the edit page. Alternately, you can stash the record's id in a hidden form field when you call the form up and then pass it back as part of the post.

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
echo anchor('site/updateRecords','Save');
```

try use

```
echo form_submit('mysubmitname', 'Save!');
```

anchor can't submit form data by default. If you use ajax, create javascript function which serialize form data and post to the server.
i hope this help

Comment: do you know how to update the db with the data without knowing the id?

Comment: i thing this not possible if you don't know what do you want update.
Add id to your form with simple pass id to form_open function: 
echo form_open('site/updateRecords/'.$id);
and modify updateRecords function declaration to this
function updateRecords($id){ //ect... }